# jQueryMobile: Are non-page-elements allowed as direct children of the body tag?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I use the following markup for my jQueryMobile app:

```
<body>
    <div id="someDiv">Foo</div>

    <div id="portrait" style="display:none">
        <div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
            <!-- Portrait content goes here -->
            Hello user!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="landscape">
        <div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
            <!-- Landscape content goes here -->
            Sorry, this app does not support landscape mode. Please rotate your device.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In order to display different content for portrait and landscape mode (of the smartphone devices where the app runs on) I switch the according divs on and off:

```
if (deviceIsInLanscapeMode() == true){
    $("#landscape").css("display", "block");
    $("#portrait").css("display", "none");
}
else{
    $("#landscape").css("display", "none");
    $("#portrait").css("display", "block");
}
```

Now, that leads me to two questions:

1. In all jQueryMobile examples codes that I read so far I noticed that pages (=div's with `data-role="page"` set) are **direct children** of the `<body>` tag. As you can see in my html markup above, I wrapped my pages into container divs. Is this a "bad idea" for jQM apps?
2. The very first child div (with id="someDiv") is just a div without a page that I enable or disable (display:none) from time to time. Could this be a problem for jQueryMobile?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea, as you will no longer be able to take full advantage of the jQM features. (You are not even coding according to the jQM standards anymore.)

Multiple divs with data-role="page" attribute is supposedly for multi-page template structure, where "... Each "page" block needs a unique id (id="foo") that will be used to link internally between "pages" (href="#foo"). When a link is clicked, the framework will look for an internal "page" with the id and transition it into view..." Please check http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html. At any given time, only one of the "pages" is active, identified by $.mobile.activePage.

For your requirement, I suggest using only one div with data-role="page" as follows:

```
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="portrait-content">
                Hello User!
            </div>
            <div class="landscape-content">
                Not Supported.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and use CSS3 media query as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
        div.portrait-content {
            display: none;
        }
        div.landscape-content {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
        div.portrait-content {
            display: block;
        }
        div.landscape-content {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```